# Kotlin coroutines not running launch on main

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have following code:

```
 Timber.d("Calling coroutine from thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    scope.launch {
        Timber.d("Current thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        runTest()
    }

 suspend fun runTest() {
    coroutineScope {
        launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Timber.d("Running from thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }
}
```

If I run it. App crashes with no error in log.
In my log I see:

> Calling coroutine from thread: main
>
> Current thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2

But I don't see entry with **Running from thread:**

This is done in viewmodel
My scope looks like this:

```
val scope: ViewModelCoroutineScope = ViewModelCoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

class ViewModelCoroutineScope(
    context: CoroutineContext
) : CoroutineScope {

    private var onViewDetachJob = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = context + onViewDetachJob

    fun onCleared() {
        onViewDetachJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've just tried your code and it works fine.  `Calling coroutine from thread: main` `Current thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1` `Running from thread: main`

Comment: I've moved this to a different place, but still getting same problem. I've tried switching  launch(Dispatchers.Main) to  launch(Dispatchers.Default) and it works, but that is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to a different machine I finally got some errors about Dispatchers.MAIN not working.

In the end all I had to do was replace all raw coroutine dependencies with:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1")
```